# Decorators in class methods

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-decorators

I'm trying to apply decorator from another class on method in my class...
it is my implementation of this Telegram API wrapper library:
https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI

But in my example want to use it not from script - but as method of class like that:

```
class Bot:

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.bot=telebot.TeleBot(key)

    def start(self):
        self.bot.polling()

    # Handle '/start' and '/help'
    @self.bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
    def send_welcome(self,message):
        self.bot.reply_to(message, """\
        Hi there, I am EchoBot. \
        I am here to echo your kind words back to you. \
        Just say anything nice and I'll say the exact same thing to you!\
        """)


    # Handle all other messages with content_type 'text' (content_types defaults to ['text'])
    @self.bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
    def echo_message(message):
        self.bot.reply_to(message, message.text)
```

All `self` are highlighted ... and certainly not working - will be glad if someone can explain what im doing wrong?
The original example trying to customize is:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)

bot.polling()
```

Comment: you should not be storing key inside a variable in a class.just pass it and use it. And have you tried using it without the self keyword?

Answer (score 2):

for those who might need it - solution i found - was to put the functions inside Ctor - and not to apply decorators to class methods .... :

```
class Bot:

def __init__(self, key,greting):
    self.key = key
    self.bot=telebot.TeleBot(key)
    self.greting=greting

    # Handle '/start' and '/help'
    @self.bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
    def send_welcome(self, message):
        self.bot.reply_to(message,self.greting )

    # Handle all other messages with content_type 'text' (content_types defaults to ['text'])
    @self.bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
    def echo_message(message):
        self.bot.reply_to(message, message.text)

def start(self):
    x = threading.Thread(name=self.greting, target=self.bot.polling,)
    x.start()
```

Comment: Did that really work? The `send_message` and `echo_message` are defined inside init method. I don't think you can access them as bot methods. `x.send_welcome('some_message')` will raise `AttributeError`

Comment: hi - yes it works - because im actually never accessing them : it is kind of event handlers assigned ... so it works

Answer (score 0):

`self` though a keyword is more of a placeholder variable name for the 1st argument for all methods that is always the instance object (except for `classmethod` where 1st argument is the class itself and `staticmethod` where there is neither)

For any method, even if you use `this` instead if `self` as 1st argument of any method, you can access all the object attributes as `this.foo` or methods as `this.bar()`.

So technically, you don't have access to the object outside any method. The decorator is at the outer most level where you cannot access object (which is passed only to methods as the 1st argument)

A complex and unnecessary workaround I can think of is to write a static method that will help you catch the `self` object from argument and then access it's `message_handler`

Answer (score 0):

I think that proper method is to use lambda functions. You can pass more than one parameter to it and get **self** from outer scope.

So, i finished with next sample

```
import telebot


class Telegram:
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.channel = telebot.TeleBot(token, parse_mode=None)

        start_dict = dict(
            function=lambda msg, obj=self: obj.start_handler(msg),
            filters=dict(
                commands=["start"],
            )
        )
        self.channel.add_message_handler(start_dict)

        self.channel.polling()

    def start_handler(self, message):
        print("START command")


test = Telegram("your-token-here")
```

You can run it from console and it will print **START command** every time you send **/start** to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should set object of TeleBot() in method start().

```
import telebot
from decouple import config as key

class TelegramBot():
    def bot(self):
        bot = telebot.TeleBot(key('token'))

        @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
        def start(message):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Sup, Sani :)")
        
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)

TelegramBotSpot().bot()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Variaveis:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.bot = telebot.TeleBot(token='')

        @self.bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
        def _process_command_start(message):
            self.process_command_start(message)

        self.bot.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=123)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    # Começando a programar :
    
    def process_command_start(self, message):
        self.bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ola mundo')


Variaveis()
```

Comment: Please, avoid leaving comments in non-English languages when you can :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.filters.command import Command

class MyBot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Bot: Bot

    async def cmd_start(self, message: types.Message):
        await self.Bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello Ukraine')

    async def run(self, aToken: str):
        dp = Dispatcher()
        dp.message.register(self.cmd_start, Command('start'))
        self.Bot = Bot(aToken)
        await dp.start_polling(self.Bot)
```

Comment: Hello, please include some explantation as to why this is the solution.